# How to change Docker config of an already running container?

Tags: docker, docker-compose, sentry

I have installed [Sentry onpremise](https://github.com/getsentry/onpremise) and after some time tinkering I got it to work and changed the `system.url-prefix` option to the correct URL using the command line. However there are 2 problems still:

- This option is not persistant
- You cannot do the same for the `mail.from` option, which can only be set before running.

There are 3 config files at play, but not all of them register and that makes it confusing.

1. sentry.conf.py

Containing

```
SENTRY_OPTIONS['system.url-prefix'] = 'https://sentry.mydomain.com'
SENTRY_OPTIONS['mail.from'] = 'sentry@mydomain.com'
```

2. config.yml

Containing

```
mail.from: 'sentry@mydomain.com'
system.url-prefix: 'https://sentry.mydomain.com'
```

3. docker-compose.yml

[image]

Restarting the containers does not load the new config.

[Related issue](https://github.com/getsentry/onpremise/issues/13). However I don't know what to do after changing the config like in the comment (`SENTRY_OPTIONS['mail.from']`)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to make your modified config files visible inside the container.

If they are built into the image (possibly via COPY or ADD in the `Dockerfile`), then restarting your container does not help, because you're doing it on an old image. You should be rebuilding the image, stopping the old one and starting the new. Rather annoying and error-prone way.

Better way is to "mount" your files via volumes. Docker volumes can be single files, not only directories. You can add the section `volumes` in your `docker-compose.yml`:

```
my_container:
  image: my_image
  volumes:
    sentry.conf.py:/full/path/to/sentry.conf.py/in/the/container
    config.yml:/similar/full/path/to/config.yml
  ports:
    ...
  command: ...
```

There's a chance you already have some volumes defined for this particular container (to hold persistent data for example), then you need to simply add volume mappings for your config files.

Hope this helps. All the best in the New Year!

Comment: But how can I reload it after mapping the volumes? Because it still loads the old config files. I want to keep postgres in order to keep the logged exceptions.

Comment: If you properly map the files via volumes, then by issuing `docker-compose restart my_container` (or, simply, `docker restart my_container` because it's already present) the new files are injected into the container. I use such workflow dozen times a day on a regular basis and I'm propagating my changes this way.

Comment: If you happen to have no desired effect, then maybe you are putting the files in a wrong place. You can play with running container via `docker exec -ti my_container /bin/bash` and find your config file there, then put the full path to the `volumes` section in `docker-compose.yml`.

Answer (score 2):

if the configuration files are stored as docker configs, then I found this guide to work...

https://medium.com/@lucjuggery/about-using-docker-config-e967d4a74b83

- Basically add update as a NEW config
- tell service to remove the old and then add the new config as the one to use.  Service will need to be restarted
- now you can remove the old docker config

this is not very nice, and if you want to name the new config with the old config identifier, you have to repeat it again!

Arrggghhh....

Comment: Correct, "One thing you do need to understand about (docker) config objects and secrets: they can’t be updated."

Comment: Yes only replaced with one of a different name.  So you you want to use the same name, you have to replace it with a new name, then replace that with the same config with the old name.

I found doing this is important for docker-compose stacks, as it then means the stack will still be able to handle the config after replacing twice as it will again have to correct name.

Answer (score 1):

This is how you can edit an existing docker container config:

1. stop container:

   `docker stop <container name>`
2. edit config:

   `docker run -it -v /var/lib/docker:/var/lib/docker alpine vi $(docker inspect --format='/var/lib/docker/containers/{{.Id}}/config.v2.json' <container name>)`
3. restart docker

Comment: The question has a assumption that you do not want to stop the container.   If the stack has multiple copies of a service, then sure you can take down each service and replace it one by one.   But if there is only one service, well then you don't really want to stop the service.

Comment: This would be a way to persist config when the container restarts, otherwise you can shell into the container and do what you need.

Comment: What's the idea behind doing the edit inside the docker? Can't you just `vi` that file directly?

Comment: If you have vi in your shell, you can; the idea for this is to be universally accessible. :D